# Is "I visited grandparents." right?

Tags: possessives

Is "I visited grandparents." right?
I think we say "I visited my grandparents."
However, if I don't use 'my', is it right grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, grammatically.

It is probably incorrect in other ways.  It means you visited lots of old people, and in particular, all of these old people had had grandchildren. It would be a very odd situation that you would say that.

> The school is doing a survey about what old people think of their grandchildren.  I visited grandparents to interview them.

So you don't say that.  You might say "I visited old people" or "I visited Joe's grandparents".

> As part of our school's community action on loneliness the students visit old people in the town. I visited two old people yesterday.

Comment: upvoted because you actually managed to invent a context in which "I visited grandparents" could actually be used!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it may not say what you mean to communicate, because "I visited grandparents" means "I visited some unspecified grandparents of somebody somewhere, who may or may not have been my own".

You may say "I visited the grandparents" if you like, which is equally valid but less personal -- it may be put that way by a precocious child trying to sound more grown up.

Of course it is still left unspecified exactly *which* set of grandparents you visited (ultimately every person has or had two pairs), and of course it may need to be left to the speaker to provide the context. (It probably does not matter in casual conversation: "What did you do this weekend?" "I visited my grandparents." No more needed.